# Perspective PageView Navigation in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have read the below article/tutorial
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/18/perspective-page-view-navigation/

I am trying to make this work from angularjs, below is the fiddler
http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZs5y/

Its working with following two issues.

1. Mouse click hand icon visible allover the page. ( I want it to be visible only on the button).
2. On Mobile devices, I am seeing little delay and flickering effect.

I am new to Angular, any ideas how to improve this.

Update: Issue 1 solved [fiddler link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZs5y/6/).

Update 2: After adding "ngTouch" module there is no delay on mobile but flickering effect is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make .perspective.modalview and container cursor property to auto to remove unnecessary pointer from the screen. also add style="cursor:pointer" to button.

**css:**

```
.perspective.modalview {
cursor: auto;
}

.container{
cursor: auto;
}
```

Comment: removing "cursor: pointer" from .modalview .container solved issue 1.
but now container is not showing the hand icon on mouse hover after modalview in view. 

also add style="cursor:pointer" certainly helped.

Comment: The one I suggested is a cleaner approach.Nevertheless cool :)

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZs5y/6/ is working and issue 1 is solved.
Thanks @Vaibhav for "cursor: pointer" hint to understand how mouse hover enable/disable works. "cursor: auto" didn't help.

issue 2 is still there..

Comment: I have solved the 1st issue with @Vaibhav hint, and 2nd issue is not resolved yet. Once its done I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: Issue2: It's not flickering, the button focus/active getting blinked[ At the initial position where we touched it to reveal the navbar] after the transition and transform has completed. same happens for container when it gets clicked to get back to initial position i.e closing the navbar.